# T-SQL can I use an alias to avoid find and replace throughout a Query

Tags: t-sql, alias

I have a long query which refers to a single field repeatedly.

I'd like to run this repeatedly, but against different fields.

Here's a simplified example in pseudo-code:

```
*Use #MyField = field1*
select  #MyField from mytable1 where #Myfield is not null order by #Myfield desc
```

I'd like to then change the first line from

`... = field1` to `...=field2` and re-run

I know I could just do Find & Replace but could I do an Alias in the way I've described?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: no, you can't, unless you use dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL for that:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + @myfield + ' FROM mytable WHERE ' + @myfield + ' IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ' + @myfield

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Make sure you only set `@myfield` to a reliable value, otherwise your query will be prone to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  The real-world query is quite long and using dynamic SQL would of course work  but would make the query more difficult to tweak.

Comment: @user70576: tough luck!